# search database from multiple form fields

Tags: django, forms

I have the following case. I have a form with 3 fields which are submitted with POST method. Then the fields are captured and a search using Q is made on the database:

```
query = Model.objects.filter( Q(field1=field1) & Q(field2=field2) & Q(field3=field3))
```

The problem is that I would like to dynamically use the fields that are filled not the empty ones. That means that the query will contain one or two or three criteria depending on the user.

I have managed to perform the search I describe with nested `if` but considering adding extra fields it gets bigger and bigger.

thanks

Comment: Please show your nested if code or complete code.

Comment: generally either one keyword searched in many fields (as in django admin) or multiple keywords with and query

Answer (score 0):

You can write generic function to generate a query based on fields passed-in.

```
def generate_query(**kwargs):
    query = Q()
    for database_field, value in kwargs.items():
        query_dict = {database_field:value} 
        if value:
            query &= Q(**query_dict)
    return query
```

And use it:

```
data = {"name":"john", "age__gte":25} # your post data
query = generate_query(**data)
objects = SomeModel.objects.filter(query)
# generally: SomeModel.objects.filter(request.POST)
```

Comment: your generate_query function `generate_query` is returning queryset for last value only; instead of `<Q: (OR: ('age__gte', '25'), ('name', 'john'))>` it is returning `<Q: (AND: ('age__gte', 25))>`

Comment: @Gahan, you are wrong, it generates `<Q: (AND: ('name', 'john'), ('age__gte', 25))>` query so please check something before you write a comment

Comment: I used an approach similar to szymon's answer and it worked. have a nice day. thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have query field like below:

```
field = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2', 'field3': None}
```

You can filter to remove null field as below:

```
non_empty_field = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1], field.items()))  # output: {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
```

For performing and query you can write

```
Model.objects.filter(**non_empty_field)  # equivalent to Model.objects.filter(field1='value1', field2='value2')
```

to perform and query you don't need Q() object

For performing or query you can write:

```
Model.objects.filter(eval('|'.join(['(Q({}="{}"))'.format(i,j) for i,j in non_empty_field.items()])))
```

according to current `field` example above query will be equivalent to:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(field1=value1) | Q(field2=value2))
```

Comment: Using `eval` is bad choice. What does happen when user enter fields like this: `field={'field1':'"fails"'}`? You need to avoid such code, input from user is not trustable and such code is vulnerable.